# Consider the IVP $y'=y^{1/3};y(0)=0,t\ge 0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Consider the IVP $y'=y^{1/3};y(0)=0,t\ge 0$.

a. Is there a solution that passes through the point (1,1)? If so, find it.

b. Is there a solution that passes through the point (2,1)? If so, find it.

c. Consider all possible solutions of the given IVP. Determine the set of values that these solutions have at $t=2$.

**My attempt**

$y'=f(y)=y^{1/3}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}=(-\infty,\infty)$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(y^{1/3})=\frac{1}{3y^{2/3}}$. Because $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is undefined when $y=0$, it follows that the IVP has existence of a solution that is valid near $t_0=0$?

$y'=y^{1/3}$

$y^{-1/3}dy=dt$

$\int y^{-1/3}dy=\int dt$

$\frac{3}{2}y^{2/3}=t+C \Rightarrow y^{2/3}=\frac{2}{3}t+C \Rightarrow y=(\frac{2}{3}t+C)^{3/2}, t \ge 0$

$y(0)=0 \Rightarrow 0=(C)^{3/2} \Rightarrow C=0$

I see that $\phi_1(t)=(\frac{2}{3}t)^{3/2}$, $\phi_2(t)=-(\frac{2}{3}t)^{3/2}$, $\phi_3(t)=0$ are solutions of the IVP.

Because the ODE is an autonomous first-order differential equation of the form $y'=f(y)$, all possible solutions of the given IVP are translations given by

$y=\chi(t)=\begin{cases}
       0, &  \hspace{2mm} t<t_0 \\
       \pm(\frac{2}{3}(t-t_0))^{3/2}, & \hspace{2mm} t \ge t_0\\
     \end{cases}$

$\phi_3(t)=0$ is the only equilibrium solution since $y':=0 \leftrightarrow y^{1/3}=0 \Rightarrow y=0$, which is unstable since $y'=-|y|^{1/3}, \forall y<0$, whereby $y'<0$ when $y<0$ and $y'=y^{1/3}>0$ when $y>0$? This means that solutions that begin near the constant function $\phi_3(t)=y_0=0$ move away from the function as $t$ increases, meaning that we can "join" the $\phi_3(t)=0$ solution with any one departing from it which is evident from the graph of $\chi(t)$?

a.)

$t=1 \wedge y=1 \Rightarrow 1=\pm(\frac{2}{3}(1-t_0))^{3/2} \Rightarrow 1=(\frac{2}{3}(1-t_0))^{3/2} \Rightarrow 1=\frac{2-2t_0}{3} \Rightarrow 3=2-2t_0 \Rightarrow -2t_0=1 \Rightarrow t_0=-\frac{1}{2}$. Because $t_0 \ge 0, t_0 \ne -\frac{1}{2}$, so there isn't a solution that passes through the point $(1,1)$.

b.)

$t=2 \wedge y=1 \Rightarrow 1=\pm(\frac{2}{3}(2-t_0))^{3/2} \Rightarrow 1=(\frac{4-2t_0}{3})\Rightarrow 3=4-2t_0 \Rightarrow 2t_0=1 \Rightarrow t_0=\frac{1}{2}$. Because $t_0=\frac{1}{2} \ge 0$, there is a solution that passes through the point (2,1).

The solution is given by $\psi(t)=(\frac{2}{3}(t-\frac{1}{2}))^{3/2}, t\ge 0$

c.)

$\chi(t)$ is undefined when $\frac{2}{3}(2-t_0)<0\Rightarrow2-t_0<0\Rightarrow t_0>2$

Thus, $Y(t)=\begin{cases}
       0, &  \hspace{2mm} t_0>2 \\
       \pm(\frac{2}{3}(2-t_0))^{3/2}, & \hspace{2mm}0 \le t_0 \le 2\\
     \end{cases}$

My book says the answer to part c. is $|Y| \le (4/3)^{3/2}$. Is that because $Y=\pm(\frac{2}{3}(2-0))^{3/2}=\pm(\frac{4}{3})^{3/2} \Rightarrow |Y|=(\frac{4}{3})^{3/2}\approx1.5396$ if $t_0= 0$, which is greater than $|Y|$ when $t_0=1 \wedge t_0=2$ since $|Y|=(\frac{2}{3})^{3/2}\approx0.5443$  when $t_0=1$ and $|Y|=0$ when $t_0=2$?